# store results from method in data form

Tags: laravel, vue.js, google-maps, tailwind-css, laravel-jetstream

I am going to preface this with I have NOT done this in a LONG time and my mind is mud. So no picking on me just remind me what I am doing wrong or not remembering.

NOTE: This is VueJS 3 / Tailwind 3 inside a Laravel 9 Jetstream Project

I have a method...

```
locatorButtonPressed() {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    position => {
                        console.log(position.coords.latitude);
                        console.log(position.coords.longitude);
                    },
                    error => {
                        console.log(error.message);
                    },
                )
            },
```

and I have a form data

```
data() {
            return {
                form: this.$inertia.form({
                    name: '',
                    email: '',
                    password: '',
                    password_confirmation: '',
                    birthdate: '',
                    user_latitude: '',
                    user_longitude: '',
                    user_city: '',
                    user_region: '',
                    user_country: '',
                    location: '',
                    terms: false,
                })
            }
        }
```

I want to store `position.coords.latitude` and `position.coords.longitude` from the method in the form Data under `user_latitude` and `user_longitude` respectfully.

What am I forgetting???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data properties can be accessed via `this.PROPERTY_NAME`. For example, to set `form.user_latitude`, use `this.form.user_latitude = newValue`.

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    locatorButtonPressed() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
           position => {
             this.form.user_latitude = position.coords.latitude;
             this.form.user_longitude = position.coords.longitude;
           })
    },
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-set-data-properties?file=src/App.vue)